# Angular 1 Angular File Saver SaveAs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filesaver.js, angularjs-3rd-party

I am having issue with Angular file saver module from http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/

I am installing the package using npm install --save and injecting it into my controllers as shown on the readme for alferov's angular file saver and I am getting the following error. I can not use 'import' and 'let' commands as I am using an old version of javascript and I cannot update my version of javascript as old version is needed.

```
saveAs is not supported. Please include saveAs polyfill
```

Any ideas of what is needed to be done to resolve this issue? Is updateing javascript the only way?

Thank you

Comment: File `dist/angular-file-saver.bundle.js` contains all required dependencies and grants access to both Blob.js and FileSaver.js polyfills via Blob and SaveAs services.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I installed it using npm in my node_modules directory. I'm adding the following 'node_modules/angular-file-saver/dist/angular-file-saver.bundle.js' as a npmDependency in gulpfile.js

Comment: sorry @georgeawg since all I have done is described above